# Saving details using Parse

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am unable to view saved data in the `parse.com` dashboard.Secondly how to retrieve data and store in recyclerview using parse and adapters.Whats wrong with the code.Thanks in advance
Mainactivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import parse.example.com.parseregistration.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    EditText firstName,lastName,age,dob;
    Button saveOne,saveTwo,showDetails;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firstName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.fn_Input);
        lastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ln_Input);
        age=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.age_input);
        dob=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.dob_Input);
        saveOne=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
        saveTwo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.saveBtn2);
        showDetails=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sdBtn);
        final ParseObject user=new ParseObject("userdata");
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this);
        saveOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                user.put("firstname",firstName.getText().toString());
                user.put("lastname",lastName.getText().toString());
                user.put("age",age.getText().toString());
                user.put("dob",dob.getText().toString());
                user.saveInBackground();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SAVED!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Userdata.java

```
public class UserData1
{
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private int age;
    private String dob;

    public UserData1()
    {
        //Default Constrcuctor
    }
    public UserData1(String firstname,String lastname,String age,String dob)
    {
        firstname=firstname;
        lastname=lastname;
        age=age;
        dob=dob;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getDob() {
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(String dob) {
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String toSreing()
    {
        return firstname+"\t"+lastname+"\t"+age+"\t"+dob;
    }
}
```

MyRecyclerView.java

```
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.msit.example.bunty.regform.R;
import com.msit.example.bunty.regform.entities.DataStore;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;


public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery;
    //ArrayList<UserData> userDataStore=new ArrayList<UserData>();
    private MyRecyclerAdapter myRecyclerAdapter=this;
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_view,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

       /*holder.fNameView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getFirstName());
        holder.lNameView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getLastName());
        holder.addressView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getAddress());
        holder.cityView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getCity());
        final String city=userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).city;
        */
        holder.cityView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),city,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(userDataStore==null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(!userDataStore.getDataStore().isEmpty()&&userDataStore.getDataStore()!=null)
        {
            return userDataStore.getDataStore().size();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

         TextView fNameView;
         TextView lNameView;
         TextView addressView;
         Button cityView;
         CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            fNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fn_view);
            lNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ln_view);
            addressView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addr_view);
            cityView=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_view);
            cardView = (CardView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.card_list);
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: What error do you get? Put `ParseObject user=new ParseObject("userdata");` after `Parse.initialize(this);`

Comment: Put a `SaveCallback` interface as an argument into your `saveInBackgroud` method. If `ParseException` as returned value is `null` then your data should be shown in the dashboard.

Comment: no error..the code runs fine

Comment: Did you put `ParseObject` initialization after the `Parse.initialize(this)` as abeikverdi said?

Comment: `Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this);
        final ParseObject user=new ParseObject("userdata");
        saveOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
    }`

Comment: Hm... what about you post us a log trace when you click on  the `saveOne` button?

Comment: `01-19 04:20:53.379 3728-3770/parse.example.com.parseregistration W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-19 04:20:53.379 3728-3770/parse.example.com.parseregistration W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdfb3af20, error=EGL_SUCCESS
01-19 04:20:55.257 3728-3770/parse.example.com.parseregistration E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xe8382070`

Comment: Did you follow every step at [Parse quick guide](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing)? Do you have any other error in log trace related to Parse library?

Comment: i created a new project from scratch,Its working fine now..Thank you everyone for your valuable suggestion.

Comment: Can someone explain how to get data and store in recycler view.Ive mention the code above MyRecyclerView.java

Comment: use parsequery findInBackground.. and on success callback notify adapter

Comment: can u please show me with a code.As i mentioned i am a newbie in android

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, dont make your parse object final, that makes it immutable, meaning it cannot be modified or added too... Also, i think its best practice to put the parse initialization stuff in the application class, otherwise your reinitalizing everytime your activity starts

Comment: i removed it..still there is no data being saved in parse cloud

Comment: Try using the save callback, new SaveCallback() (i think) and check whether the error is null. Also what is the ACL level of this object? Is your user priveleged enough?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your refactored code, I suggest you not to do `Parse` queries within `Adapter`. Better do that somewhere inside `Activity` and after you retain data, pass these values to `MyRecyclerAdapter`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.msit.example.bunty.regform.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    //ParseQuery<ParseObject> parseQuery;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<UserData> userDataStore = new ArrayList<UserData>();
    private MyRecyclerAdapter myRecyclerAdapter=this;

    public MyRecyclerAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserData> data) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        userDataStore = data;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_category,parent,false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {

       /*holder.fNameView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getFirstName());
        holder.lNameView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getLastName());
        holder.addressView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getAddress());
        holder.cityView.setText(userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).getCity());
        final String city=userDataStore.getDataStore().get(position).city;
        */
        holder.cityView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),city,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if(userDataStore==null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if(userDataStore !=null && !userDataStore.isEmpty())
        {
            return userDataStore.size();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView fNameView;
        TextView lNameView;
        TextView addressView;
        Button cityView;
        CardView cardView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
            super(itemLayoutView);
            fNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fn_view);
            lNameView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ln_view);
            addressView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.addr_view);
            cityView=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.city_view);
            cardView = (CardView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.card_list);
        }
    }
}
```

This is simple example how to retain data from Parse, put these code somewhere inside `MainActivity`:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("userdata");
        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    ArrayList<UserData> userDataList = new ArrayList<UserData>();
                    UserData userData;
                    for (ParseObject object : list) {
                        userData = new UserData();
                        userData.setFirstName(object.get("firstname"));
                        userData.setLastName(object.get("lastname"));
                        //...
                        userDataList.add(userData);
                    }
                    MyRecyclerAdapter adapter = new MyRecyclerAdapter(MainActivity.this, userDataList);
                    // instance of RecyclerView declared somewhere in your Activity
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    // Something went wrong, see exception
                }
            }
        });
```

Btw. [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects) you can find well explained Android dev guide :D